# Consistent /dev names for USB hard drive and card reader

Tags: linux, udev

I have a Raspberry Pi (but that should be immaterial) to which, normally, connect:

- a USB hard drive
- a SD card adapter.

I've been getting inconsistent device names. Sometimes the hard drive shows up at `/dev/sda`, and the card reader as `/dev/sdb`. Today, for reasons unknown (to me), the hard drive is a `/dev/sde`, and the card reader is at `/dev/sda`. There aren't any other disk-like devices.

How do I make those consistent, without having to become a UDEV expert, preferably? :-)

Added: This is Arch Linux with systemd and built-in UDEV.

Comment: Might want to mention your OS even though we could guess it's Raspbian it's best to be explicit.

Answer (score 3):

You have other ways of identifying disks that don't change - try using `/dev/disk/by-uuid/<longstring>`.

You can use the `blkid <sdXx>`  on the partitions to find out the UUID.

Comment: Using /dev/disk/by-uuid/<uuid> works, however once the USB drive is mounted, the output of `mount` shows the device mounted as either /dev/sda or /dev/sdb.  My problem is when the USB drive is powered off and then back on it comes back with a different device name such as /dev/sdc, but mount still shows the device mounted using its previous name.  See my question here for more details: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177648/raspbian-usb-storage-device-name-changing-after-usb-device-power-cycle